# Rendering JSON with Play! and Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a simple question regarding rendering JSON object from a Scala class. Why do I have to implemet deserializer ( read, write ).

I have the following case class:

```
case class User(firstname:String, lastname:String, age:Int)
```

And in my controller:

```
val milo:User = new User("Sam","Fisher",23);

Json.toJson(milo);
```

I get compilation error: No Json deserializer found for type models.User. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.

In my previous project I had to implement a reader,writer object in the class for it to work and I find it very annoying.

```
object UserWebsite {
  implicit object UserWebsiteReads extends Format[UserWebsite] {

    def reads(json: JsValue) = UserWebsite(
      (json \ "email").as[String],
      (json \ "url").as[String],
      (json \ "imageurl").as[String])

    def writes(ts: UserWebsite) = JsObject(Seq(
      "email" -> JsString(ts.email),
      "url" -> JsString(ts.url),
      "imageurl" -> JsString(ts.imageurl)))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I really recommend to upgrade to play 2.1-RC1 because here, JSON writers/readers are very simple to be defined (more details [here](http://mandubian.com/2012/09/08/unveiling-play-2-dot-1-json-api-part1-jspath-reads-combinators/))

But in order to help you to avoid some errors, I will give you a hint with imports:
- use these imports only! (notice that json.Reads is not included)

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.Writes._
```

and you only have to write this code for write/read your class to/from Json (of course you will have `User` instead of `Address`:

```
implicit val addressWrites = Json.writes[Address]
implicit val addressReads = Json.reads[Address]
```

Now, they will be used automatically:

Example of **write**:

```
Ok(Json.toJson(entities.map(s => Json.toJson(s))))
```

Example of **read**(I put my example of doing POST for creating an entity by reading json from body) please notice `addressReads` used here

```
def create = Action(parse.json) { request =>
        request.body.validate(addressReads).map { entity =>
          Addresses.insert(entity)
          Ok(RestResponses.toJson(RestResponse(OK, "Succesfully created a new entity.")))
        }.recover { Result =>
          BadRequest(RestResponses.toJson(RestResponse(BAD_REQUEST, "Unable to transform JSON body to entity.")))
        }
}
```

In conclusion, they tried (and succeded) to make things very simple regarding JSON.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using play 2.0.x you can do

```
import com.codahale.jerkson.Json._

generate(milo)
```

generate uses reflection to do it.

In play 2.1 you can use Json.writes to create a macro for that implicit object you had to create. No runtime reflection needed!

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

implicit val userWrites = Json.writes[User]
Json.toJson(milo)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using jerkson (which basically is wrapper to jackson) in my project to convert objects to json string.

The simplest way to do that is:

```
import com.codehale.jerkson.Json._
...
generate(milo)
...
```

If you need to configure the ObjectMapper (e.g. adding custom serializer/deserializer, configuring output format, etc.), you can do it by creating object which extends `com.codehale.jerkson.Json` class.

```
package utils

import org.codehaus.jackson.map._
import org.codehaus.jackson.{Version, JsonGenerator, JsonParser}
import com.codahale.jerkson.Json
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.module.SimpleModule
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize

object CustomJson extends Json {

  val module = new SimpleModule("CustomSerializer", Version.unknownVersion())

  // --- (SERIALIZERS) ---
  // Example:
  // module.addSerializer(classOf[Enumeration#Value], EnumerationSerializer)
  // --- (DESERIALIZERS) ---
  // Example:
  // module.addDeserializer(classOf[MyEnumType], new EnumerationDeserializer[MyEnumType](MyEnumTypes))

  mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
  mapper.setSerializationConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig.without(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES))
  mapper.registerModule(module)
}
```

To use it in your codes:

```
import utils.CustomJson._
...
generate(milo)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this is very simple. Firstly import:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
```

Thanks to the fact, that User is a case class you can automatically create Json writes using Json.writes[]:

```
val milo:User = new User("Millad","Dagdoni",23)
implicit val userImplicitWrites = Json.writes[User]
Json.toJson(milo)
```

I haven't found it in the docs, but here is the link to the api: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Json$

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I'd use the JSON.format macro.

```
import play.api.libs.json._
implicit val userFormat = Json.format[User]
val milo = new User("Sam", "Fisher", 23)
val json = Json.toJson(milo)
```